# Launch AVD Manager in Android Studio 2.3.3 without creating Android Project

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

In `Android Studio 2.3.3`, I know how to launch AVD Manager from my Android Project in Android Studio.  I can use `Tools --> Android --> AVD Manager`.

[image]

But if I don’t have an Android Project, how can I open the AVD Manager? In the landing screen Configuration, AVD Manager is not listed. Is there any way to launch AVD Manager without creating Android Project?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941999/how-to-open-avd-manager-gui-without-opening-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

No You can not do that. You need to have project created in Android Studio.

Comment: Yes. It is for all version. But still confirm at your end.

Comment: I am trying to run a project created with React Native on an Android emulator, and the only instruction given there is to "create a new AVD". No instructions are given how. Every single google search instructs to use the "Tools" menu, but there is no such menu. React Native doesn't create an Android Studio project, so there is nothing to open. I only want to configure and run an emulator, not create a new Android Studio project. Is the only way to do that really to create some dummy project, so that Android Studio will show the Tools menu, which it otherwise refuses to show?