# How to open AVD Manager GUI without opening Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

As I'm not developing my app with Android Studio, but I'm still using the Android emulator.

What's a nice way for me start up my emulator without doing this?

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open some project
3. Click the AVD Manager button

*I'm not looking for a complete CI replacement, but if there's a long command I can run to open the GUI I'm happy.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run AVD Emulator without Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718973/run-avd-emulator-without-android-studio)

Answer (score 6):

Cd to your Android SDK location using PowerShell

```
cd C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
```

and type

```
.\emulator.exe -list-avds
```

this will show your available avds, choose your device copy the name and replace the following

```
.\emulator.exe -avd "<virtualDeviceName>"
```

Eg:

```
.\emulator.exe -avd "Pixel_2_API_27"
```

You can simply create a .bat file

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
@echo Running the emulator
.\emulator.exe -avd "Pixel_2_API_27"
```

Comment: There's two big issues here. First things first, the `emulator.exe` file is'nt in the `\tools` folder but in the `\emulator` folder. Secondly a batch file will never have a `#!/bin/sh` hashbang in it. You should replace it with `@echo off` instead. Hashbangs are for bash scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions, in my case both directories work IDK :/

Answer (score 5):

What about a script that show current avds defined and let you choose which one start ?
I called it avdmanager.bat in root of SDK (variable ANDROID_HOME set on SDK root needed):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=0
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -list-avds`) DO (
  SET /a count=!count!+1
  SET var!count!=%%F
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,%count%) do echo %%i) !var%%i!
@echo digit number of virtual machine to run or 'q' to quit
set /p choice=""
if "%choice%"=="q" goto end
@echo !var%choice%!
%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -avd !var%choice%!
:end
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Can you provide Linux version bash too?

Comment: I'm not a bash frequent user to be able to realize that, but I think it should not too difficult to do

Comment: bat code corrected, thank you @Votagus for your answer

Answer (score 3):

Just a minor fix with the command -list-avds in @alrama's answer (the extra space), I cannot add comments yet.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET count=0
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -list-avds`) DO (
  SET /a count=!count!+1
  SET var!count!=%%F
)
for /l %%i in (1,1,%count%) do echo %%i) !var%%i!
@echo digit number of virtual machine to run or 'q' to quit
set /p choice=""
if "%choice%"=="q" goto end
@echo !var%choice%!
%ANDROID_HOME%\emulator\emulator.exe -avd !var%choice%!
:end
ENDLOCAL
```